# Multiple Device ID's being counted in App+Web Analytics for Active/Total Users despite using UserID

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

We are using the new app+web analytics set up for our application since we would like to unify the analytics across our Web and Native applications.

The implementation is working however despite us setting a `user_id` user property, we are finding that multiple deviceId's are being counted for one `user_id` which means that whenever we try and use metrics such as "Sessions per User" or "Active Users" these are inaccurate, as a user who clears their cookies, or reinstalls the app would be counted twice.

Is there any way to prevent tracking of DeviceId's and only use our `user_id` user property?